# Python won't update in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, version, sublimetext

I've been trying to reconcile versions of Python between Sublime Text and Terminal. To that end, I figured I'd just update my version of Python to the lastest version.

After running the installer for 3.11.0, and running the scripts in the packaging, the Python used by Sublime Text now reads that it's running 3.11.0, but in Terminal

> python3 --version

outputs

> Python 3.8.8

*For the record, I made sure to close and reopen Terminal after install.

I'm struggling to figure out how to get both the editor and terminal to run on the same version, and why running the python installer for 3.11 hasn't updated the terminal version

Comment: you can specify the version you want to run like `python3.11 <script>` in your terminal

Comment: You need to edit your `$PATH` variable to include the Python 3.11 installation's `bin` directory as the first item. There is lots of information on how to do that online.

Answer (score 0):

if after executing

#Linux
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.11

#MacOS
brew install python

It continues to give problems and you restarted the PC, it still does not work, check the commands with the following link

https://4geeks.com/how-to/how-to-update-python-in-terminal

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34675644)